# WordPress is_page_template not working right init action

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code above into functions file of my theme. I did this code to logout the user "messenger" when another page that not use the template page_forms is requested.

But, when I access some page that use this template, I'm being redirected to the homepage and the session is closed. Which makes me believe that the is_page_template statement is not working properly.

Does anyone have any tips?

```
function messenger_session(){

    $current = wp_get_current_user();

    if( isset($current->user_login) && $current->user_login == 'messenger' && !is_page_template('page-forms.php') ):

        $redirect_to = get_home_url();

        wp_logout();
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        exit;

    else:
        return;

    endif;
}
add_action('init','messenger_session');
```

**UPDATE**

After research, I solve the problem changing 'init' from add_action to 'template_redirect'. This change make the user messenger stay logged in on page-forms.php.

But, the second step is make logout of this user if any other template is required. So, to make this happen, I make some changes in my code:

```
function messenger_login(){

    $current = wp_get_current_user();

    if( is_page_template('page-forms.php') && !isset( $current->user_login ) ) :

        $username = 'messenger';
        $user       = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );
        return;

    elseif( !is_page_template('page-forms.php') && isset( $current->user_login ) && $current->user_login == 'messenger' ):

        $redirect_to = get_home_url();

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
        die;

    else:
        // do nothing

    endif;
}

add_action('template_redirect','messenger_login');
```

And the problem now is that after messenger login on page-forms.php, the logout happens automatically withou respect the second statement of the function where the template needs not be page-forms.php to fire the logout (without redirect to home -- is crazy!).

When I comment the function wp_clear_auth_cookie, the problem stop. But the function lose your porpouse.

Answer (score -1):

That function `is_page_template` is working correctly just make sure you're using correct path of your `page_form` template if that template is inside any folder like `folder/page-form.php` then you must need to use that full path after your theme folder suppose if your template is inside `templates` folder then you must need to pass `templates/page-forms.php` within `is_page_template` function

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: the function is writed on functions.php theme file and the page-forms.php is a template located on theme root folder. In another cases the call for this page is working fine, but using this function, not.

Comment: That looks weird because same code is working for me with default WP theme, can you try to update `init` action to `wp` action that could help you

Comment: Thanks for yout time. But after try to use 'wp' instead 'init' the problem is keeping. I solve this question changing 'init' by 'template_redirect'. Any way, now I have the second part of the mistety to solve. This part was mentioned on original post through an update. I will apprecitate to receive any help! Thanks!